# What are some behavioral anomalies with data structures that use reference counting in STL?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, garbage-collection, containers

Scott Meyer in "Effective STL" says that one of the things to think about while deciding which data structure to use is whether the container uses reference counting or not. He says that there are some behavioral anomalies with this approach.

What are some of them? Why do containers like 'string' and 'rope' have anomalous behaviors?

Comment: You seem to think that string has to be reference counted...

Comment: Multi-threading can be an issue if the critical section that manipulates the counter isn't atomic.

Comment: Just curious, what chapter is this in?

Comment: One such anomaly is that, in ref-counted containers, it can be hard to predict exactly when you incur the cost of deleting something, where in a non-ref-counted container, you can (more) easily determine where it is either going out of scope or being explicitly deleted.

Comment: Was flagged as poll/list, but I think I'm going to let this go if the book didn't elucidate what these anomalous behaviours were.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, the typical example is `std::string`. Besides performance issues with locking in multithreaded programs, there are thread-less problems with reference-counted strings. Imagine this:

```
string s = "hello";
string t = s;                   // s and t share data
char &c = t[0];                 // copy made here, since t is non-const
```

The problem is that the non-const `operator[]` must make a copy of the string if it's shared, since the returned reference could be used later to modify the string (you can assign it to a non-reference `char`, but `operator[]` doesn't know it should behave any differently). On the other hand the *const* `operator[]` should avoid making a copy, because that would eliminate all benefits of reference counting (it would mean you *always* make a copy in practice).

```
const char &get_first(const string &s) {
    return s[0];                // no copy, s is const
}

string s = "hello";
string t = s;                   // s and t share data
const char &c1 = get_first(t);  // no copy made here
const char &c2 = t[0];          // copy made, since t is non-const
// c1 just got invalidated (in fact, it's pointing at s[0], not t[0]).
s[0] = 'X';
printf("%c, %c\n", c1, c2);     // outputs "X, h"
```

As you can see, this distinction is confusing and may cause really unexpected behavior.

Here's an old article about copy-on-write semantics and its impact on performance: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/045.htm.

Here's the proposal with motivation to change `std::string` to not be reference-counted in C++11 standard: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2534.html. This is what the above example is based on.

Comment: Excellent answer to a vague question :)

Answer (score 1):

As a sample one anomaly that can happen with reference counted strings, in particular strings with "subpart" handling (with a start/end slice), is "*unfortunate locking*".

Let's imagine you allocate memory for the entire text of a file. You then parse your file and use some "slice()", "left()", "mid()" or equivalent method. You might end locking the entire string for the file whereas maybe only a very small part of it contains actually textual data (the remain being already parsed numbers, punctuation or whatever). You might therefore have used *more memory* than necessary in the end, while controlling more easily peak usage. There might be a second problem in this case if you use multi-threading and use intensively some of the strings in various threads: *unnecessary memory contention*, the reference count of the strings might get incremented/decremented all the times and the atomicity might get int the way, slowing done all the threads.

There is nothing against reference counting though, as long as you know the potential issues in your application and prevent them (in this case simply make the strings "alone" by copying them).

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, reference counting suffers from the usual multi-threading issues of race conditions, deadlocks or excessive synchronization to avoid either.

Then you have problems of context which would normally require closure-like behaviour i.e. objects may need to be captured after they have apparently gone out of scope, but this may be avoided by STL, I am not an STL expert.

There's a discussion here which talks about various baroque edge-cases associated with smart pointers: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t689414-c-primer-4th-edition-reference-counting-smart-pointers.html

Answer (score 1):

In Item 13 Meyers elaborates about issues with multi-threading and refcounted strings.

It depends heavily on the exact implementation of `std::string` and locking and the usage pattern.

It **can** be a problem if an apparently harmless usage of a `std::string` in a multi-threaded environment causes delays because of hidden locks. The penalty of such locks and context switches in a loop can be huge. But it should never cause deadlocks. 

It does not have to be a problem. The book is >10 years old. Thread implementations have improved in the meantime. Linux-Futexes e.g. behave much smoother in most cases.

Another point: (by me, dunno if Meyers discussed this too...)
A refcounted `std::string` means it has copy-on-write semantics. That's generally a Good Thing. The actual copy is deferred until it is actually needed. But this also means the price for the copy has to be paid at a point which is possibly hard to predict.

Comment: Locking hasn't exactly gotten cheaper with multi-core processors. Locks by necessity require a globally visible write. And the problem with COW is that you often need to pay the price of locking when you can't determine whether a lock is needed and you need to err on the side of caution.

Comment: No locking has become cheaper in modern implementations. Acquiring a free lock and releasing a lock no one is waiting for takes almost no cost at all. Only the other 2 cases are still expensive.